# Postgrest filter does not seem work with fields from related table

Tags: postgrest

I would like to retrieve records of `kiscourse` where the related `joblist.job` has a value that contains `tech` within the `joblist.job` string value.

This returns the expected results:

`/joblist?select=job,kiscourse_id(*)&limit=10&job=ilike.*tech*`

This does not:

`/kiscourse?select=*,joblist(*)&limit=10&joblist.job=ilike.*tech*`

And according to: https://postgrest.com/en/v4.1/api.html#embedded-filters-and-order, this seems to be the intended:

---

```
> GET /films?select=*,roles(*)&roles.character=in.Chico,Harpo,Groucho
> HTTP/1.1
```

> Once again, this restricts the roles included to certain characters
>   but does not filter the films in any way. Films without any of those
>   characters would be included along with empty character lists.

---

Is there any way to accomplish the above (besides procedures)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgrest now [supports top-level filtering](https://postgrest.org/en/stable/references/api/resource_embedding.html#top-level-filtering) by adding the `!inner` flag to the select query.

From the docs:

> In order to filter the top level rows you need to add `!inner` to the embedded resource. For instance, to get only the films that have an actor named `Jehanne`:
>
> ```
> GET /films?select=title,actors!inner(first_name,last_name)&actors.first_name=eq.Jehanne HTTP/1.1
> ```

Comment: Do you know since which version this is supported? Might help future readers. Latest right now is v11.2 in any case.

Answer (score 2):

the `joblist.job` filter you have there will affect only the entities on the second level, it does not apply to the first level.

The way to read this query 
`/kiscourse?select=*,joblist(*)&limit=10&joblist.job=ilike.*tech*`
is this:

Give me 10 rows from `kiscourse` with all the columns, and for each row, i want the `joblists` for that row that are named `*tech*`

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this though?

Comment: Start from the other end with `/joblist` as top level.

Comment: The other options are a view that does the join or a stored procedure

Comment: Ohhh a view with a join. Yes that would work perfectly!

Comment: Actually it wouldn't as there are joblist is a many to one relationship...  So the results would have potential duplicates.